Documenting props in a React/Typescript component
How can I document React component props so that the comments appear in the documentation for the component itself?
Here's an example. Suppose you have this component:
type TableProps = {
  /** An array of objects with name and key properties */
  columns: Column[];
  /** An array of row objects */
  rows: Row[];
};

/** A table component */
const Table = ({
  columns,
  rows
}: TableProps) => {

When a developer looks up this component's documentation, they just see A table component. It would be so awesome if they instead saw something like this:
A table component

Props:
* columns: Column[] - An array of objects with name and key properties
* rows: Row[] - An array of row objects

As far as I know this isn't possible within Typescript.
We could write out all the comments on the props again inside a comment on the component, but that feels like busy work that leads to out-of-date documentation.
Do any of the major IDEs have a plugin that solves this problem?
JSDoc
As @neaumusic commented below, I could try to solve this with JSDoc. For example, I could add a JSDoc comment to the component like this:
/**
 * A table component
 * @param {object} props
 * @property columns - An array of objects with name and key properties
 * @property rows - An array of row objects
 */
const Table = ({
  columns,
  rows
}: TableProps) => {

This means I get useful documentation about the props when inspecting the component itself. Perhaps this is the best solution available. It's still not ideal, though. For one thing, I don't want to write out the props' types in two places, so I'm inclined to omit the types from the JSDoc comment, but that feels strange. Also, now I no longer see relevant documentation when inspecting the prop itself (a small downside). The biggest downside is that each prop's type and description are in two places.
The JSDoc pattern above feels like a B+ solution. React and Typescript are such a common combination nowadays, I'm surprised there isn't an A-grade solution. Is there one?

This question isn't a good fit for this site. You're asking for recommendations and the acceptance criteria are subjective and arbitrary. Also, please don't spam tags. This question is not about any of the editors you tagged.

Part of my question is: Do any of the major IDEs have a plugin that solves this problem? It's not clear how to solve it in TS, so perhaps what's needed is an IDE plugin that knows how to include prop comments in the component documentation.
I suppose most people following the IDE tags expect questions tailored to those specific editors - fair enough, so I've untagged them.
As for subjectivity, @neaumusic's response below is an objectively good response.

I think you want to look at JSDoc, which uses that syntax for commenting and annotating functions. You can use lines like @returns and @param, and there probably exists an npm package to generate JSDocs from your types automatically

Good point! I added some thoughts about JSDoc in the question above.
